# Как узнать пользователя, если на сайте нет регистрации

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Возник такой вопрос: нужно добавить на сайт возможность редактирования занесенных данных, но регистрации на сайте нет, то есть по паролю и логину не определишь. Хотела сделать проверку по ip, но оказывается, если используются анонимные прокси-сервера извлечь ip невозможно. Как поступить? Может просить вводить специальный пароль для возможности редактирования? Но это уже как регистрация получится...

Comment: Так и сделайте. При вводе сообщения пусть вводят кодовое слово, которое нужно будет ввести для редактирования.

Comment: Спасибо за совет!

Comment: Используйте авторизацию через VK/Twitter/FaceBook/Google/etc

Comment: Тоже попробую!

Comment: Есть риск, что половина введет туда всем известный триграмматон и будет редактировать чужие сообщения таких же умников.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вообще-то можно ставить cookie с каким-нибудь уникальным значением (хэш поголовья тушканчиков в Средней Азии * фазу луны) и у сообщения хранить этот хэш..  Хэши совпали - можно редактировать..

Comment: Не вариант. Если кука будет удалена, то никто и никогда уже не сможет отредактировать сообщение. Плюс у пользователя может быть пять устройств для выхода в интернет и пять браузеров на каждом из устройств.